# How to apply CSS on texte label beside an input?

Tags: html, css

I have this small code contains a text (label) and a text input

What I am looking for is to have text + input take 100% of the div (i.e 20% for text and 80% for input) and the text should be in the middle of its zone with a background has the same height as the input.

I tried with span, with applying `background-color: blue;` on the div but It didn't have any impact.

Do you know ho to do it?

Thank you in advance.

```css
#zoneFiltre {
    width: 100%;
}

.champs {
    width:20%;
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: middle;
    color: white;
}

#filtreMultiAptitudes{
    width:80%;
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<div id="listeMultiAptitude">
    <div class="zoneFiltre">
      <label class="champs">filter: </label>
      <input type="text" id="filtreMultiAptitudes" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `Flexbox` you can use `flex: 0 0 80%` on `input` and `flex: 1` on `label` also its `text-align: center`

```css
.zoneFiltre {
  display: flex;
}
.champs {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
#filtreMultiAptitudes {
  flex: 0 0 80%;
}
```

```html
<div id="listeMultiAptitude">
  <div class="zoneFiltre">
    <label class="champs">filter: </label>
    <input type="text" id="filtreMultiAptitudes" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `<label>` tag is an inline element so it cannot take `width`/`height`. Display it as `inline-block`.

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}

#zoneFiltre {
    width: 100%;
}

.champs {
    display: inline-block;
    width:20%;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}

#filtreMultiAptitudes{
    display: inline-block;
    width:79.3%;
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<div id="listeMultiAptitude">
    <div class="zoneFiltre">
      <label class="champs">filter: </label>
      <input type="text" id="filtreMultiAptitudes" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The space between both elements is because the `<input>` tag has a default `border`. You can use a lower percentage (as shown above) or use `calc` function to rest the width that occupy the border.

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}

#zoneFiltre {
    width: 100%;
}

.champs {
    display: inline-block;
    width:20%;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}

#filtreMultiAptitudes{
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(80% - 4px);
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<div id="listeMultiAptitude">
    <div class="zoneFiltre">
      <label class="champs">filter: </label>
      <input type="text" id="filtreMultiAptitudes" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Another solution and **the best** in my opinion is to use `box-sizing: border-box` which calculates the `width` taking as part of the `width` the `borders` and `paddings` of an element.

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}

#zoneFiltre {
    width: 100%;
}

.champs {
    display: inline-block;
    width:20%;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}

#filtreMultiAptitudes{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<div id="listeMultiAptitude">
    <div class="zoneFiltre">
      <label class="champs">filter: </label>
      <input type="text" id="filtreMultiAptitudes" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it looks so much better, but there is still a white space between the label and the input, is it possible to make it like attached?

Comment: @Chinovski It is because the body tag has a default margin and the input tag has a default border (that occupy just 4 pixels but does not allow to make 20%-80%). You can put a lower percentage or use `calc` function.

Comment: @Chinovski Look at my edit question. Now I think it could be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display:table` if you fancy this.

```css
form {
    display:table;
    border:1px dotted black;
    width:100%;
}
form p {
    display:table-row;
}
label, form span {
    display:table-cell;
    padding:0.5em 0;
}
label {
    background:blue;
    color:white;
    vertical-align:top;
}
span input, span textarea {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:100%;
}
textarea {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <p>
        <label for="input1">A label: </label>
        <span><input type="text" id="input1" /></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="input2">A longer label:</label>
        <span><input type="text" id="input2" /></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="txt">Textarea:</label>
        <span><textarea id="txt" rows="5" cols="15"></textarea></span>
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you @Midas, it's the fisrt time I see this method